# How to get Java Script value in jsp page but in Expression Language Variable?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, jstl

In java script code i am using append method for append data in html page, but i want same data in Expression Language variable. Any Solution ?

```
$('.attrPrdctOfCityId').click(function () {
    var uri = $(this).data('uri');
    alert(uri);
    $( ".innerPocid" ).append(uri); //Instead of this I want uri value in jsp page but in expression language variable
});
```

Comment: You would need to use AJAX to get the client-side JS variable to the server side Java code. Have a google around as there are lot of questions and tutorials covering this already.

Comment: I need only in jsp page not in server side, for that ajax is required ? @Rory McCrossan

Comment: Bhagesh, JSP runs in server side and generates HTML output. If you rightclick and *View Source* in webbrowser, you'll see no single line of JSP code. If you take a step back and tell which problem exactly you're trying to solve, for which you possibly incorrectly thought that this all is the right solution, then we may be able to come with the correct solution for that requirement.

Comment: Ok sir, I want to forward this var uri value in jsp page for check a condition like ${uri eq pocid} so how to forward from java script to jsp page ? @BalusC

Comment: Which problem exactly you're trying to solve with this? Describe the functional/business requirement.

Comment: I opened a modal inside for each loop in jsp page by using this anchor tag <a data-uri="${mapCombo.productOfCityId}"  class="waves-effect  attrPrdctOfCityId waves-light btn modal-trigger red darken-1" href="#modal1">Buy Now</a> after that  by the help of data-uri "data-uri="${mapCombo.productOfCityId}" I get the value in java script code you can see above in my question code, after that I want to use same value in same jsp page but in another for each loop which will be execute after click on this modal, So Am i using right way if any alternate so please suggest me ? @BalusC